# DropDown Menu gone wrong

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make it when the mouse goes over the image 8 links or so will go down but it gets covered by the mega menu... How do i fix this?
I have tried to put important where the background is for the dropdown part but that didnt work... any ideas? Anyone that could help would be helpful & thanks

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
   * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   body {
      margin: 0;
   }

   .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }

   .navbar a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
   }

   .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 16px;  
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font: inherit;
      margin: 0;
   }

   .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #832893;
   }

   .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
   }

   .dropdown-content .header {
      background: #832893;
      padding: 16px;
      color: white;
   }

   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
   }

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
   .column {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #ccc;
      height: 250px;
   }

   .column a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      cursor: pointer;
   }

   .column a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
   }

/* Clear floats after the columns */
   .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
   }

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
   @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .column {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      } 
   }
/* profile Drop part that is not working correctly */
   .profilebtn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0.8%;

   }
   .profile-dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
   }
   .profile-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1 ;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
   }
   .profile-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
   }
   .profile-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
   .profile-dropdown:hover .profile-content {display: block;}
   .profile-dropdown:hover .profilebtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="navbar">
     <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="header">
            <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
          </div>   
         <div class="row">
           <div class="column">
              <h3>Media Centre:</h3>
              <a href="homepage.html">link 1</a>
              <a href="#">link 2</a>
              <a href="#">link 3</a>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
              <h3>category 2</h3>
              <a>Link 1</a>
              <a>Link 2</a>
              <a>Link 3</a>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
            <h3>category 3</h3>
              <a>Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
              <h3>category 4</h3>
              <a href="#">link 1</a>
              <a href="#">link 2</a>
              <a href="#">link 3</a>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="profile-dropdown">
       <img src="profilePicture.jpg" class="profilebtn">
       <div class="profile-content">
         <a>Link 1</a>
         <a>Link 2</a>
         <a>Link 3</a>
         <a href="#">Link 4</a>
         <a href="#">Link 5</a>
         <a href="#">Link 6</a>
         <a href="#">Link 7</a>
         <a>Link 8</a>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase this?  "goes over the image 8 links or so will go down"

Comment: Links get covered beacuse your navbar has overflow: hidden, if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
    .profile-dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .profile-content {
        /*...*/
       top: 40px;   
    }
    .profile-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        flex: 0 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .profile-dropdown:hover .profile-content {    
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
     }
```